# Android multiple numbers on dialler

Tags: android

I am developing an app for my college. But I am stuck at the dialler option. Every-time I click on the call button the same number appears on the dialler even though select a different content of the spinner. I want to open different numbers on the dialler for different names selected.

Java Code:

```
public class ContactTeacher extends Activity
{
    List<String> spinnerArray1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> spinnerArray2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> spinnerArray3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contactstudent);

        spinnerArray1.add("Select To Call");
        spinnerArray1.add("Abhijit Dey");
        spinnerArray1.add("Amit Ghosh Roy");
        spinnerArray1.add("Tanay Bhadra");
        spinnerArray1.add("Dhirodatta Subba");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray1);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.studentspinner);
        sItems.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinnerArray2.add("Select Email");
        spinnerArray2.add("Abhijit Dey");
        spinnerArray2.add("Amit Ghosh Roy");
        spinnerArray2.add("Tanay Bhadra");
        spinnerArray2.add("Dhirodatta Subba");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray2);

        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner sItems2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.studentspinner2);
        sItems2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        spinnerArray3.add("Select Message");
        spinnerArray3.add("Abhijit Dey");
        spinnerArray3.add("Amit Ghosh Roy");
        spinnerArray3.add("Tanay Bhadra");
        spinnerArray3.add("Dhirodatta Subba");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray3);

        adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner sItems3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.studentspinner3);
        sItems3.setAdapter(adapter3);

    }

    public void stdcall(View v)
    {

                if(spinnerArray1.contains("Abhijit Dey"))
                {
                    Intent b = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:000000000"));
                    startActivity(b);

                }
        else if(spinnerArray1.contains("Amit Ghosh Roy"))
        {

                Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:2222222222"));
                startActivity(a);

        }
                else if(spinnerArray1.contains("Tanay Bhadra"))
                {

                    Intent c = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:3333333333"));
                    startActivity(c);

                }
                else if(spinnerArray1.contains("Dhirodatta Subba"))
                {

                    Intent d = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:44444444444"));
                    startActivity(d);

                }
                else
                {

                    Intent e = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:55555555555"));
                    startActivity(e);

                }


    }


}
```

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/studentspinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/studentspinner2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/studentspinner3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/stdcallbutton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/studentspinner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/studentspinner"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/studentspinner"
        android:src="@drawable/call"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="stdcall" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/stdmailbutton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/studentspinner2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/studentspinner2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/studentspinner2"
        android:src="@drawable/mail"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="stdmail" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/stdmsgbutton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/studentspinner3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/stdmailbutton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/stdmailbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/message"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="stdmsg" />
</RelativeLayout
```

Comment: `if(spinnerArray1.contains("Abhijit Dey"))` this will always be true because you put `Abhijit Dey` in the array at the beginning of the Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `stdcall()` method is wrong. You are using Spinner wrongly.

```
// Condition below is always true
// This way, the method always enter here regardless spinner seleciton
if(spinnerArray1.contains("Abhijit Dey"))
```

You should check the curret spinner selected item.
Like below:

```
public void stdcall(View v) {
    Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.studentspinner);
    if(sItems != null) {
        Intent dialIntent = null;

        switch(sItems.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
            //case0 is spinner title... Ignore it
            case 1:
                //Abhijit Dey
                dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:000000000"));
                break;
            case 2:
                //Amit Ghosh Roy
                dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:2222222222"));
                break;
            case 3:
                //Tanay Bhadra
                dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:3333333333"));
                break;
            case 4:
                //Dhirodatta Subba
                dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:44444444444"));
                break;
        }

        if(dialIntent != null)
            startActivity(dialIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much sir. It really helped. Thanks a Lot...!!:)

Comment: If the answer is right, kindly request to accept it. This way, this question will be closed...